# Click Jacking for older browsers

Tags: javascript, html, clickjacking

I need to add click jacking protection to a website.  I know this can be done in IIS with setting the X-Frame option for newer browsers.  For older browsers, I know you need to add frame buster - which is some javascript etc.

Here is my main question: If you have to add the javascript for the frame busters for the older browsers - do you have to add it to EVERY single html page in your website?  My website has A LOT of different html pages etc. Just need a good opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need it on every page, or it's pointless -- if a given page is unprotected, then a malicious actor can put it in a frame and do whatever he or she wants to it, including, say, making it look like a checkout form.

The easiest way to do this will be to put it in an external script that you load for each page; don't put the script itself in each page. If you have any kind of template system, it's even easier; just add it once to your header file.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I do not have a template website, so I'll have to add a external script to every page.  I haven't done much javascript over all, so what is the best way to call the external script code on page load for each page?  I know I need a link in the header etc.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. You just need to add something like `<script src="my_click_jacking_blocker.js"></script>` to the header of each page, where my_click_jacking_blocker.js is your script name.

Comment: Yes, that will be added for sure - but is that enough or do I need to put something on the <body> tag for each page to call the my_click_jacking_blocker.js function in my external style sheet.

Comment: The script will be loaded by simply including the above tag. Now, if you put the relevant code in a function, then yes, you need to trigger that function somehow, either in the .js file or in the onLoad attribute of the body element. I would recommend that you look at this reference: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Thanks a bunch, Ed. Appreciate your help and information.